# Functionality of Beego syntax 'Ctx.Input.GetData('<variable-name>')'

Tags: go, beego

I am new to beego and goLang. I came across a code. If someone could explain the flow it would be very helpful. It is a GET API. I think `Prepare()` is like a filter. What I don't understand is `c.Ctx.Input.GetData("customerid")` and `c.Ctx.Input.GetData("customergroupid")` functions. Can someone explain me what `GetData` is doing and how we can pass values to them?

```
// URLMapping ...
func (c *CampusHomeController) URLMapping() {
    c.Mapping("GetOne", c.GetOne)
}
func (c *CampusHomeController) Prepare() {
    if c.Ctx.Input.GetData("customerid") == "" {
        returnJSON := postCampusHomeJSON{}
        returnJSON.Code = 403
        returnJSON.Msg = "Invalid Session"
        c.Data["json"] = &returnJSON
        c.ServeJSON()
        c.StopRun()
    }

    if c.Ctx.Input.GetData("customergroupid") == "" ||             
        c.Ctx.Input.GetData("customergroupid") == nil {

        returnJSON := postCampusHomeJSON{}
        returnJSON.Code = 404
        returnJSON.Msg = "User not a campus manager"
        c.Data["json"] = &returnJSON
        c.ServeJSON()
        c.StopRun()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GetData is used to get data from filters in your controllers. It allows you to pass values other than just strings.

From the Beego documentation:
GetData
Get value of Data in Input

SetData
Set value of Data in Input. GetData and SetData is used to pass data from Filter to Controller
https://beego.me/docs/module/context.md

Comment: So filter are parameters which are passed through the url,  like /cm/profile?customergroupid=14?

Comment: No a filter is like middleware in other web frameworks. Something that can execute before the main body of the api call is made, so "customergroupid" might be looked up in a filter added to `ctx.Input` using the SetData method. And then retrieved in the api call by `ctx.Input.GetData`. Filters docs: https://beego.me/docs/mvc/controller/filter.md